# Rails simple_form error: false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

in my app I have form that looks like this

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = f.input :name, error: false
  = f.input :surname, error: false
```

Is there any way to avoid this repetitions (error: false)?

Comment: What is `error` in your code?

Comment: error is a simple_form method, when you changed it to true it not show field errors. For example when you left name blank and click submit, field will be red but without any message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If they're all of the same type, something like this should work:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  - [ :name , :surname ].each do |field|
    = f.input field, error: false
```

If not, you could use a hash or something, instead of an array, and specify the type, as well.

It appears that simple form has the following option:

> If you want to pass the same options to all inputs in the form (for
>   example, a default class), you can use the :defaults option in
>   simple_form_for. Specific options in input call will overwrite the
>   defaults:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, defaults: { input_html: { class: 'default_class' } } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username, input_html: { class: 'special' } %>
  <%= f.input :password, input_html: { maxlength: 20 } %>
  <%= f.input :remember_me, input_html: { value: '1' } %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

From https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

So, in your case:

```
= simple_form_for @user , defaults: { error: false } do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :surname
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through an array of symbols

```
simple_form_for @user do |f|
  [:name, :surname].each do |element|
    f.input element, error: false
  end
end
```

Comment: It's good idea but my real form is very complicated, many fields have different options and this is impossiible to do by loop.